# Is Robotech on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I ask because it's considered an adaptation of three works (Macross, Southern Cross and Mospedia).

While I would expect questions on those works to be on topic, I'm not sure how much leeway there is for derivative works.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia says it's an anime,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotech) and we're here to discuss anime.

As long as it's clear that's what we're talking about, what's the problem?

Comment: Derivative works are not always appreciated, and we're early in the site's development (obviously), so I wanted to know where we stood with that.  As we see questions on these works we'll see how the policy develops, but I wanted to get an initial feel.

Comment: By that logic we wouldn't be able to cover the Battle Royale manga either, even though it was a novel first (and later a live-action film). Or for a more fitting "Western" analogy, we wouldn't be able to include "My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic" in a Western Animation SE just because it was a toy line first. The distinction feels silly because it IS silly.

Comment: Robotech is a separate show, with a separate continuity, and a plot separate to the original three shows.  It reuses animation and such, but it should still be considered in all other ways to be a different entity.

Comment: Ah, but what about US produced sequels such as Shadow Chronicles?